# A 1968 AHSME problem with exponents

Tags: exponential-function, contest-math, exponentiation, number-comparison

> Given the three numbers $x,y=x^x,z=x^{x^x}$ with $.9<x<1.0$. Arranged in order of increasing magnitude, they are:
>
> $\text{(A) } x,z,y\quad \text{(B) } x,y,z\quad \text{(C) } y,x,z\quad \text{(D) } y,z,x\quad \text{(E) } z,x,y$

Hi, hope you are doing well. I was solving this 1968 AHSME Problem 29.

Unfortunately, I could not solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated. Also, I was wondering what would happen if say $0<x<0.9$ or $x<0$ and other cases. Please help.

> **My Thought Process**
>
> Since $x<1.0$, $x^x$ must be less than $x$ but I couldn't reason out the further.
>
> Also, in the case $x > 1$, $x^{x^x} > x^x > x$ as it increases due to $x$ being greater than $1$.

Comment: No, $x^x>x,$ in the same way that $\sqrt{x}>x$ when $0<x<1.$

Comment: Can you show me your full final answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$1>x^{1-x},$$ which gives
$$x^x>x,$$
which gives 
$$x^{x^x}<x^x.$$
Id est, it's enough to compare $x^{x^x}$ and $x$.

Since, $$x^x<1,$$ we obtain 
$$x^{x^x}>x.$$
Thus, $$x^x>x^{x^x}>x.$$

Comment: Thank you Michael so much.

Comment: @Vasu090 You are welcome!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I'm still confused, why did you start with 1 > x^(1-x)
and how did you get x^x > x from it
and how from x^x > x you got that x^(x^x) < x^x ?? Please explain your reasoning more I'm confused.

Comment: @hikaru jakafura because $0<x<1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Compare $\ln x$ , $\ln y$ , $\ln z$