# A Geometry Problem with multiple parallel lines, trapezoids.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, contest-math, triangles

> In $\Delta ABC, PQ || BC$ where $P$ and $Q$ are points on $AB$ and
>   $AC$ respectively. The lines $PC$ and $QB$ intersect at $G$. It is
>   also given $EF || BC$, where $G \in EF, E \in AB$ and $F\in AC$ with
>   $PQ = a$ and $EF = b$. Find value of $BC$.

Hi. Hope you are doing well. I was stuck in the geometry problem given above.

I think the Midpoint Theorem has some role to play here but can't figure it out. Please help. This was asked in HOMC 2006. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{EG}{BC}=\frac{PG}{PC}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{GC}{PG}}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{BG}{GQ}}=\frac{GQ}{BQ}=\frac{GF}{BC},$$
which says $EG=FG=\frac{1}{2}b$

Can you end it now?

I got $$BC=\frac{ab}{2a-b}.$$

Comment: That is the correct answer 

Comment: @Vasu090 Do you want an explanation?

Comment: I found it. Thanks for helping

Comment: @Vasu090 You are welcome!

Comment: Can you please do me another favor? This is the other problem I posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3296842/a-1968-ahsme-problem-with-exponents. Can you help me with that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a line parallel to the side $AB$ through $F$. Such line intersects $BC$ at $K$ and the extension of $PQ$ at $J$. Then the triangles $\triangle ABC$, $\triangle APQ$,  $\triangle FJQ$, $\triangle FKC$ are all similar. It follows that 
$$\frac{b-a}{a}=\frac{c-b}{c}\implies c=\frac{ab}{2a-b}$$
where $c=|BC|$.