# Problem with exponents and inequalities

Tags: contest-math, exponential-function, exponentiation, number-comparison

Hello I tried to solve this problem, below:

> Given the three numbers $x,y=x^x,z=x^{x^x}$ with $.9<x<1.0$. Arranged
> in order of increasing magnitude, they are:
>
> $\text{(A) } x,z,y\quad \text{(B) } x,y,z\quad \text{(C) } y,x,z\quad
> > \text{(D) } y,z,x\quad \text{(E) } z,x,y$

I know the answer is A. I found the solution which is :

> since $0<x<1$ then ${x^x} > x$  and since $x > 0$ and $x < 1$ then ${x^x} < 1 $. Thus ${x^{(x^x)}} > x$, so $z > x$.  Since $x < {x^x}$ and $x < 1$,
> we find ${x^x} > {x^{(x^x)}}$, so $y > z$ hence, in increasing order the
> quantities are $x,z,y$

I'm so confused with this step if someone here could explain in details:

Why or how did we jump from: [ since $x < {x^x}$ and $x < 1$ ] to say that [we find ${x^x} > {x^{(x^x)}}$]

Comment: If $x^x$ is greater than $x$ and $x<1$, it must mean that $x^{x^x}$ is greater than $x^x$. The exponents of these monomials fulfill the same logic if I'm not wrong.

Comment: but in the answer it says that ${x^{x^x}}$ is less than ${x^x}$. from the book and in here too this guy answered it the same but I'm confused he didn't show the full steps https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3296842/a-1968-ahsme-problem-with-exponents

Comment: The answer isn't B, it's A

Comment: @Piita can you answer my question though, I'm confused with the solution it said since x < x^x and x < 1 then x^x > x^(x^x)... why is that ??

Comment: From this photo I seem to think that maybe $y > z > x$ https://imgur.com/a/w03wieV

Comment: @AntonioDeAngelis yes exactly, but I'm confused with the reasoning that went from saying since x^x > x and x < 1 then x^x > x^(x^x) which is y > z

Comment: Because if a number $(a>1)$ is elevated to a number that is less than 1, it will make that number smaller. However, if the number is smaller than 1 $(a<1)$, then the bigger the exponent is, the smaller the number gets. Ultimately, if the base is equal to 1 $(a=1)$, then it will always be equal to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a function $f:\mathbb{R^+}\to\mathbb{R^+}$ by $f(t)=x^t$. Since $0<x<1$, we have
$$\forall t_1>t_2\in\mathbb{R^+}, f(t_1)=x^{t_1}=x^{t_2}x^{t_1-t_2}<x^{t_2}=f(t_2)$$

This shows that $f(t)$ is strictly decreasing. Hence, since we know that $x<x^x$, we know that $f(x)>f(x^x)$, giving $x^x>x^{x^x}$.

Answer (score -1):

The exponential function $a^x$ with a base $a<1$ is decreasing. Hence if $a<a^a \implies a^a>a^{(a^a)}$

Comment: an you add more context why is it "decreasing" and why does "a^x" being a decreasing function would let me go from a < a^a to a^a > a^(a^a) . think like you are explaining to someone new to all this, please.